# Fourier transform of $e^{-ax^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I'm trying to solve the following Fourier transform, or at least I'm trying to simplify it a bit

$$ \mathcal{F}(e^{-ax^2})(\xi,\eta) = \int_{\mathbb{R^2}} e^{-i(x\xi+y\eta)}e^{-ax^2}dxdy $$

for $a > 0$.
One of the problems I'm finding is that the integrand function is not summable in $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence integrating is not that immediate. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, the integral you wrote is not well defined. You have to think of $f(x,y) = e^{-ax^2}$ as a tempered distribution. Let $f_1(x) = e^{-ax^2}$ and $f_2(y) = 1$. The function $f$ can be written as $f_1 \otimes f_2$. Therefore we have
$$\mathcal F(f)(\xi, \eta) = \mathcal F(f_1 \otimes f_2)(\xi, \eta) = \mathcal F(f_1)\otimes\mathcal F(f_2)(\xi, \eta).$$

The Fourier transform of $f_1(x) = e^{-ax^2}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}$ and the Fourier transform of $f_2(y) = 1$ is $2\pi \delta(\eta)$.

So, we obtain the formula
$$\mathcal F(f) =2\pi \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}\delta(\eta).$$

Comment: Awesome thank you.
Just a thing: I believe it's $\check{\delta}(\eta) = \delta( - \eta)$. Is this correct?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not sure what do you mean by $\check \delta$. I just used that the Fouruer transform of $1$ is $2\pi \delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

Comment: Okay I said something correct, but trivial, and you are correct.
I got confused because by the inversion formula is easy provable that if $u$ is a tempered distribution, then $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}(u) = 2\pi \check{u}$, where if $f$ is a function then $\check{f}(x) = f(-x)$, if $u$ a distribution $\check{u}(f) = u(\check{f})$. But in Dirac's delta case $\check{\delta} = \delta$.
Anyway thanks again!